# Excel find and replace replacing replaced text

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Why when using find and replace in Excel are cells already replaced being recognized and replaced in a new use of find and replace? Is there any way to prevent find and replace from changing cells already replaced again? For example, Lets say I use find an replace to change all cells that say no to yes. Then, I decide to find and replace all cells with other text to yesterday, but now all the cells that were originally replaced with yes are changed and replaced to yesterday, thereby, sabotaging my purpose of find and replace. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

find "yes" and replace with "noDONE" then change "no" with "yesterdayDONE" and so on at the end last replace is:

find "DONE" replace with "" (blank), it is just a tricky work around but works.